# Android AlarmManager problem

Tags: java, android

I'm a new developer android application.I've problem about AlarmManager,I using
AlarmManager to set alert for my application.

I was set time to alert 2 time but my application was alert a one time

example,I'll set alarm at 15.30 and 16.30,My application will alert at 16.30 but not alert at 15.30.I've no idea to fix this problem,I hope someone please tell me to fix this problem

This my code

```
confirmButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) { 
        alarm();
        finish();  
       }
 });
```

This alarm method,I'll get date and time from button and use it to set calendar

```
private void alarm(){
     final String day = mBtnselectDate.getText().toString();
 final String time = mBtnselectTime.getText().toString();
 y = day.substring(0, 4);
 m = day.substring(5, 7);
 d = day.substring(8);
 ALARM_HOUR = time.substring(0, 2); 
 ALARM_MINUTE = time.substring(3); 

 year = Integer.parseInt(y);
 month = Integer.parseInt(m);
 mon = month - 1;
 date = Integer.parseInt(d);

 Hour = Integer.parseInt(ALARM_HOUR);
 Min = Integer.parseInt(ALARM_MINUTE);


Intent AlarmIntent = new Intent(Organaizer2.this, AlarmReceiver2.class);
    AlarmManager AlmMgr = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);            
    PendingIntent Sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Organaizer2.this, 0, AlarmIntent, 0);     

    Calendar alarmCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    alarmCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Hour);
    alarmCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Min);
    alarmCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    alarmCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, mon);
    alarmCalendar.set(Calendar.DATE, date);

    AlmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmCalendar.getTimeInMillis(), Sender);   

}
```

if you see problem please tell me,Thank you,Arles

Comment: This code shows one alarmCalendar instance being used to store a time for an alarm. Is there a second? Or is this code in a method which you are calling twice? If so, show us all of the relevant code please.

Comment: yes,this code in method and I call it twice

Answer (score 0):

Your second alarm is replacing the first alarm, because both use equivalent `Intent` objects. Add a call to `setAction()` on your `AlarmIntent` (BTW, recommended Java style is lowercase first letters for variables) to set a unique action string. You can also try providing a different request code (the first `0` in your call to `getBroadcast()`), though that parameter is not well documented and I am not sure if it will give you distinct alarms or not.